# How to Replace numbers to Letters

Tags: javascript, math, random

The assignment asks instead of showing number 25, 75, 125, 175, words should be shown on the page. I have set up the if statement, but for some reason the I cannot get rid of the number 25, 75, 175. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

assignment 2

```
<script>
    //start of Assignment 2-1
    var new_text = "";
    var randMax = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
    for (var i = 1; i < randMax; i++) {
        new_text += i;

        if (i == 25) {

            new_text += "Twenty Five ";

        } else if (i == 75) {
            new_text += "Seventy Five ";
        } else if (i == 125) {
            new_text += "one hundred and twenty five ";;
        } else if (i == 175) {
            new_text += "one hundred and Seventy five ";

        } else {
            new_text += " ";
        }

    }
    document.write(new_text);


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the for loop, you use `new_text += i;` . That means it will always append i to your `new_text` string. If you want to make it conditional, you need to put it in the else statement.

```
   <script>
        //start of Assignment 2-1
        var new_text = "";
        var randMax = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
        for (var i = 1; i < randMax; i++) {


            if (i == 25) {

                new_text = "Twenty Five ";

            } else if (i == 75) {
                new_text += "Seventy Five ";
            } else if (i == 125) {
                new_text += "one hundred and twenty five ";;
            } else if (i == 175) {
                new_text += "one hundred and Seventy five ";

            } else {
                new_text += i;
                new_text += " ";
            }

        }
        document.write(new_text);


    </script>
```

Comment: That won't work, new_text = "Twenty Five "; simply overwrite all the result. To fix it move "new_text += i;" line into the else statement instead.

Comment: Yeah I misread the problem at first. As soon as I realized that, I deleted my answer and edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_text = "";
    var randMax = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
    for (var i = 1; i < randMax; i++) {

        if (i == 25) {
            new_text += "Twenty Five ";
        } else if (i == 75) {
            new_text += "Seventy Five ";
        } else if (i == 125) {
            new_text += "one hundred and twenty five ";;
        } else if (i == 175) {
            new_text += "one hundred and Seventy five ";

        } else {
            new_text += i;
        }
        new_text += " ";

    }
    alert(new_text);
```

Move "new_text += i" to the else block. Now it gets run at each iteration regardless of the condition